# Updating the super class without extending it?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, extends

I was wondering if anybody has some advice for me. I have Interface (JFrame) that calls different classes (JPanels) using the CardLayout. Problem is netbeans automatically states [public class Interface_Login extends javax.swing.JPanel]. When i replace the extends with Interface and Import javax.swing.JPanel the generated code gives 2 errors on these lines:

```
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
```

Is there anyway to change the generated code within Netbeans or even update the superclass which calls the JPanel method? The Interface class has 2 setter methods to update the variables.

Edit 1:
Sorry guys. Code Provided.

Interface[JFrame]

```
package Interface;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Interface {

    String selectedDatabase;
    String db_location;
    static JPanel contentPane;

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // This JPanel is the base for CardLayout for other JPanels.
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(0,0));
        Interface_Login login = new Interface_Login();
        contentPane.add(login,"Login Window");

        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setSelectedDatabase(String selectedDatabase) {
        this.selectedDatabase = selectedDatabase;
    }

    public void setDb_location(String db_location) {
        this.db_location = db_location;
    }
}
```

Interface_Login

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Interface;

import Database.Database_Connection;
import Database.Database_Details;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author Renier
 */
public class Interface_Login extends javax.swing.JPanel{

    Database_Connection db;
    String selectedDatabase;


    String []databaseNames={"Mr Price","Mr Price Home","Spar","OK Superite","Markhams"};
    public Interface_Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel1.setText("Welcome to the database connector");

        jLabel2.setText("Please select a database:");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(databaseNames));

        jLabel3.setText("Please provide your username and password:");

        jButton1.setText("Test Database Connection");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Username:");

        jLabel5.setText("Password:");

        jTextField1.setEditable(false);

        jPasswordField1.setEditable(false);

        jButton2.setText("Exit");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Login");
        jButton3.setEnabled(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 184, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 33, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        selectedDatabase= (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        Database_Details db_Details = new Database_Details();
        String db_location = db_Details.getDatabaseLocation(selectedDatabase);
        db = new Database_Connection(db_location);
        if(db.loadDriver()){
            jTextField1.setEditable(true);
            jPasswordField1.setEditable(true);
            jButton3.setEnabled(true);
            jComboBox1.setEditable(false);
            //super.setDb_location(db_location);
            //super.setSelectedDatabase(selectedDatabase);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error", "Database Not Located", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The Problem: 
Login_Interface needs to send 2 variables (db_location, selectedDatabase) to Interface. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Your question is kinda confusing. An interface is not a class; so how can an interface be a JFrame. A layout doesn't call other objects, it just contains them. Long story short: please post the code that gives you error messages; together with the error messages. We dont have a magic crystal ball that could tell us what you did on your machine to run into errors you are giving to us ;-(

Comment: Some code would greatly improve the quality of the question.

Comment: @GhostCat Interface is not `interface` , its the name of the class with capital `I` as I understood

Comment: @svasa Maybe .. if so: using such names is highly confusing. Dont do that. Names should say what the things the "name" is ... so what is an "Interface"?

Comment: @GhostCat OP should answer you.